# Why is my jQuery.Get query parameter banned from the action method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment

I'm trying to do a `$.get()` to refresh a list, but no matter what I try, the action method either doesn't get the query parameter, or it gets a null value.

This is my page:

```
@model ParkPay.Helm.ViewModels.PublicHolidayIndexModel
@section ViewScripts
    {
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#import-link").click(function () {
                var year = $("#Year").val();
                var importUrl = "@Url.Action("Import")";
                    $.get({
                        url: importUrl,
                        data: { year: $("#Year").val() }
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
}
<section class="index-commands">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Year)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Year, Model.YearList)
    @Html.ActionLink("Import holidays for the selected year.", "Import", null, new { id = "import-link" })
</section>
<section id="index-table">
    @Html.Partial("KendoGridPartial", Model)
</section>
```

I have tried several variations on `$.get()`, and with the current one, above, a breakpoint in Chrome shows the URL to be `"/PublicHoliday/Import?year=2013"`, yet in the action method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Import(string year)
{
    var service = new PublicHolidayService(ControllerDbContext);
    service.ImportPublicHolidays(int.Parse(year));
    return RedirectToAction("Index", new { year });
}
```

the value of `year` is null. If I try `$.get(importUrl, {year: $("#Year").val() })`, I get the error that the action method is passed a null value. If I try

```
$.get({
    url: importUrl,
    data: { year: $("#Year").val() }
});
```

I get the same null value. If I make `year` an `int` in the action method signature, it doesn't even make it in and I get

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'year'

Just how the heck must I pass this parameter to `$.get`? Or, is `$.get` flawed and I must just revert back to an `$.ajax` call?

Comment: @freshbm, I did say above that I had already tried writing it like that:  *"If I try $.get(importUrl, {year: $("#Year").val() }), I get the error that the action method is passed a null value."*

Comment: Show your `routes` from `Global.asax`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please send your JSON object using - JSON.stringify(yourObject);

```
var obj = { year: $("#Year").val() };
$.ajax({
    url: importUrl,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(obj)
});
```

I was having the same problem and I solved like this.

Comment: I was sure jQuery handles that itself